# Cannot Install / Use MySQL on Amazon Cloud9 Free Account

Tags: mysql, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to run MySQL commands on a free account with Amazon Cloud9 and I cannot get it to work anyhow. I've tried all the commands I've found on the internet, including `mysql-ctl install`,  `mysql-ctl start` and `mysql-ctl cli` - all of them result in a discouraging `bash: mysql-ctl: command not found`.

I think Amazon Cloud9 may have changed their rules regarding free accounts. Please, advise what to do.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This site is intended as a programming Q&A, it's not a general help desk. For questions like this about services provided by commercial providers, your best bet is likely to contact the provider directly. While there might indeed be people here who know the answer, this is clearly off-topic for StackOverflow, so I've voted to close this question.

Answer (score 6):

These are the commands that you need. Write them to terminal.

```
sudo service mysqld start
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

To run MySQL Shell:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

To stop the service:

```
sudo service mysqld stop
```