# Cloud9 IDE: Cannot Connect to MySQL via Node

Tags: mysql, node.js, cloud9-ide

I do all my web development projects using Cloud9 (which is actually part of AWS now). Anyways I have had no problem connecting using the built in PHP functions and variables but the Node platform has been giving me some trouble. The [Cloud9 community guide](https://community.c9.io/t/connecting-php-to-mysql/1606) for connecting to MySQL was much more clear for PHP than Node, and other questions and answers I have found online have had a large array of suggests but none have worked. Here is what I would have considered my best bet:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.IP,
    user: process.env.C9_USER,
    password: "",
    port: 3306,
    database: "database_name"
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Start aws cloud9 mysql service with the code:

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

Then "host" and "password" has to be used as seen below.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '*******',
  database : 'database_name'
});
```

That is the link for how to install and start mysql service in aws cloud9 in case of anyone needs.

[aws cloud9 mysql service installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005924/cannot-install-use-mysql-on-amazon-cloud9-free-account/52044502#52044502)